# Oracle SQL Developer Cloud Wallet Mac computer error: Invalid configuration file

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am at a loss why I received the "Invalid configuration file" error on a Macintosh computer when connecting to an Oracle Cloud database using a Cloud Wallet file, see attached screenshot. Normally, the service box is populated automatically, but in this case it is empty. Therefore, the connection will not work.

Has anyone experienced this, or does anyone knows what is going on?

Thanks very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you pleas post more information such as your database version ? Follow this document https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-sql-dev182.html#GUID-14217939-3E8F-4782-BFF2-021199A908FD

Comment: The cloud database version is 19c, the SQL Developer version is 20.2. I was able to successfully connect on other Macintosh computers, but for some reason on this particular one I am receiving this error. So it must be something specific on this computer that is different.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue on the Mac computer. It seems that in newer versions of Mac OS (not sure which ones) Safari automatically unzips a zip file. So this was the problem as SQL Developer needs to load the wallet file as a zip file and not unzipped.

There is an option in Safari to turn this off:
Open Safari.
Click Preferences.
Under the General tab, uncheck the option Open “safe” files after downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with sql developer version 20.4.0.379.  It seemed to be caused by certain versions of the JDK.  Mine didn't work with jdk1.8.0_281 but was fine with jdk1.8.0_171.

Try changing the version in the SQL Developer ~/.sqldeveloper/20.4.0/product.conf file.

e.g Add the following line (after installing an earlier version of JDK):

SetJavaHome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home